# boto3 SSM: sending multiple commands in sequence

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-ssm

TLDR: What is the best way to send tens of commands to a remote instance using ssm, in sequence, such that I can get the output of each command before moving to the next one?

This question ([How to SSH and run commands in EC2 using boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645196/how-to-ssh-and-run-commands-in-ec2-using-boto3/45083322#45083322)) asks how to run SSH commands using boto3 on a remote instance. The top voted answer explains how one can use the boto3 ssm send_command function to do so:

```py
resp = client.send_command(
  DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript", # One of AWS' preconfigured documents
  Parameters={'commands': commands},
  InstanceIds=instance_ids,
)
```

However, the response for this function is a dictionary that does not contain the actual output.

An answer to a different question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67441672/3269537) helpfully answers that the `ec2.get_command_invocation` function can get the output. However, you have to essentially poll using `get_command_invocation` until the remote command has completed.

I want to run multiple commands remotely in sequence, including uploading files to the instance (without using ssh). Is there any better way to do this besides calling `send_command` and `get_command_invocation` over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way to do that. The only improvement you can make is to use **waiter** [get_waiter('command_executed')](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#waiters) provided by boto3. It essentially does the same as you would manually pool `get_command_invocation`, except that you don't have to write that loop. `boto3` does that for you.

Comment: Damn, seems like sockets or events would be an obvious use case here...

What about for file uploads? I can again use send command (use echo to pipe the data I need over the wire) but is there a way to just send files directly using ssm?

Comment: @theahura You can use scp over ssm.